# For eBook which control i should use and how to start

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to develop such an application through which i can read book ,currently i am using the Richtextbox in flow document,i dont want to use the scroll ,i prefer the navigation style i.e prev page next page start and end ,book may contains images tables  so and so ,and how do  i import books in my application

How can i achieve?

Regards,

Aamir

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at the [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx), which is meant for documents with pages.

Comment: i have already gone through this ,you also have noted in it that all book pages are written manually in XAML or some how you can write through Code, but if i have a book in doc format or in pdf then how can i import it in my application? i want to develop a book reader ,book may be in any format but i want to read it in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write code to extract the text from the word or pdf document.

You can get out the text from a Word document using Word automation.

For pdf files you can possibly use the iTextSharp library:
http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

For other formats you might be able to use the source of FBReader as a sample:
http://www.fbreader.org/downloads.php

Comment: and what about the Tables Bullets and images ? do you think that to write diiferent code for reading different format is good approach?
Is there not any way to import files?rather to read one by one?
Any other control if in your mind that i can use?

Comment: i also want to edit like bold the syntax italic and copy paste like operations on it ,Rich textbox suited me but imprting is issue as i described above

Comment: The problem you have is just that since they are different formats, you will need different code to read them. There might be controls you can find or buy that would do it for you, but inside they'd still need to use different code to read the different formats. Assuming that you write the import code and can get that to recognize when the source document use things like italic etc, then you could probably use the Rich textbox to present the information.

Comment: There are various tools that will convert from various formats to one format, possibly you could use something like that in an automated way to convert all documents to one format and then you'd just need to handle one format in your code.